# Static route for a subdomain in pimcore

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, pimcore

I need to add a static route in pimcore that only takes effect for a special subdomain. So e.g. `/de/json` should snap for the URL `api.example.org/de/json` but not for `www.example.org/de/json`.

Is this possible in pimcore? Or do I have to work with Zend Framework's `Hostname`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with "Sites", you can specify the site to use/apply for a static route (column "Site" in the static routes table view).

More on using sites: https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14551657